# C Comparison Sort Segmentation Fault when Comparing Bits

Tags: c, sorting, segmentation-fault, comparison

I've only recently started programming in C and I'm running into some trouble with a comparison sort algorithm.  I'll post the code below, but essentially I have three separate comparison functions that help sort an array of unsigned int's.

The first comparison function sorts in ascending order, the second sorts in descending order, and the third is meant to sort based on the number of 1's in the binary representation of the int - it's the last of these three that gives me my segmentation fault.

Thoughts?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* ASIZE is the size of the array to sort (number of 32-bit integers) */
#define ASIZE 100
/* NFCNS is the number of different sort functions defined in the comp array */
#define NFCNS 3

/* defines the type compare_fcn to be a pointer to a function that takes two
 * constant void pointers and returns an integer. */
typedef int (*compare_fcn)(const void *, const void *);

/* randomly permute the elements in an array of size 32-bit integers.
 * Permutation is done in place. */
void shuffle(uint32_t *a, int size) {
    int i = 0;  /* Scratch */

    /* Seed the random number generator with the current time.  Since time(2)
     * returns a time_t, the code casts it properly. */
    srandom((unsigned int) time(NULL));

    /* Permute the elements */
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++) {
    int j = random() % size;
    int k = random() % size;
    int tmp = 0;

    if (j == k) continue;
    tmp = a[j];
    a[j] = a[k];
    a[k] = tmp;
    }
}

/* Print the 32-bit array (of size integers) to stdout.  Print the integers as
 * 3-digit, zero-padded integers, 10 integers to a line. */
void dump_array(uint32_t *a, int size) {
    int i = 0;  /* Scratch */

    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if ( i % 10 == 0) printf("\n");
    printf("%03d ", a[i]);
    }
    if ((size -1) % 10 != 0 ) printf("\n");
}

/* 
 * qsort comparison functions compare the data pointed to by two pointers.  In
 * this program, the data is always interpreted as 32-bit, unsgned integers
 * (uint32_t's).  Comparison functions need to cast the pointers into the right
 * type and carry out the comparison.  The return value is <0 if the first data
 * should appear before the second, >0 if the first should appear after the
 * second, and 0 if there is no preference.
 */

/*
 * Compare the elements pointed to b a and b to each other as 32-bit integers.
 */
int compare_ab(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const uint32_t *aa = (const uint32_t *) a;
    const uint32_t *bb = (const uint32_t *) b;
    return *aa - *bb;
}


int reverse_compare_ab(const void*a, const void *b){
    const uint32_t *aa = (const uint32_t *) a;
    const uint32_t *bb = (const uint32_t *) b;
    return *bb - *aa;
}

int compare_by_ones(const void*a, const void*b){
    const uint32_t *aa = (const uint32_t *) a;
    const uint32_t *bb = (const uint32_t *) b;

    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        uint32_t temp1 = (uint32_t) *aa >> i;
        uint32_t one = 0x01;
        temp1 = temp1 & one;
        if(temp1 == one) count1++;

        uint32_t temp2 = (uint32_t) *bb >> i;
        temp2 = temp2 & one;
        if(temp2 == one) count2++;
    }

    return -(count2 > count1);
}

/* Definition of the array to sort */
uint32_t a[ASIZE];

/* Definition of the array of comparison functions */
compare_fcn comp[NFCNS];

/*
 * Main driver program.  Initialize an array with the integers from 0-ASIZE,
 * permute it, and sort it with different comparisons.  Print the initial
 * array, the permuted array, and each sort to stdout.
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 0;      /* Scratch */

    /* Initialize array and functions */
    for ( i = 0 ; i < ASIZE; i++)
    a[i] = i;

    /* Initialize function table */
    comp[0] = compare_ab;

    comp[1] = reverse_compare_ab;

    dump_array(a, ASIZE);

    /* Permute */
    shuffle(a, ASIZE);
    dump_array(a, ASIZE);

    /* Sorts */
    for (i=0; i < NFCNS; i++) {
    qsort(a, ASIZE, sizeof(uint32_t), comp[i]);
    dump_array(a, ASIZE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot `comp[2] = compare_by_ones;`

Comment: I don't think `-(count2 > count1)` gives you the return value you want from `compare_by_ones`.  If `count2 < count1`, that expression returns zero, when you probably want +1 or -1 for a `qsort` comparison function.

Comment: As @Jim mentioned, you probably wanted `count1 - count2` in `compare_by_ones` (although the function doesn't seem to be called anywhere).

Comment: More generally, turning on compiler warnings ("gcc -Wall -Werror") is an excellent habit to get into.  You would have gotten warnings (turned into failures because of the -Werror flag) that pointed you to your errors when you tried to compile your code.  Having the compiler tell you about your mistakes is so much easier than trying to find them yourself.  (If you're not using gcc, check the manual for your compiler--it almost certainly has similar flags.  If you are using clang, the flags are identical)

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have already said, your code has at least 2 bugs.

The more obvious bug is that you didn't initialize all members of the `comp` array, and so this loop:

```
for (i=0; i < NFCNS; i++) {
  qsort(a, ASIZE, sizeof(uint32_t), comp[i]);
  dump_array(a, ASIZE);
}
```

on its last iteration access `comp[2]`, which is still `NULL`. Calling a function through a `NULL` pointer is the immediate cause of the segmentation fault.

The less obvious bug is that your `compare_by_ones` `qsort` comparator returns `0` or `-1`, but never `1`, so the resulting sort order will not be correct (or even predictable).